# MS SQL - LEAD is not a recognized built-in function

Tags: sql-server

I am using MS SQL server managment studio 2014, when trying to use the function 'LEAD' or 'LAG', I get an error saying it is not a recognized built-in function, even though when hovering over the function, it does show it as a built-in function.
Everywhere I looked it says the function should be available from version 2012 and up, but I can't get it to work.
Help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!
[image of the message showing when hovering ove the function name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnmVP.png)

Comment: SSMS 2014 <> SQL SERVER 2014. Don't mistake client tool with SQL server. `SELECT @@version` if higher than `2012+` check compatibility level.

Comment: You are absolutely right, my server is 2008. I downloaded the SqlLocalDB.msi of 2014 now, do you know by any chance how I make the managment studio connect to it instead of the 2008 one? Thanks so much!

Comment: When you open SSMS, and it asks which server to connect to, enter the name\instance of your 2014 server.

Comment: Iv'e got sql server 2008 , 2012 and 2014 installed when i check version 
it states 2008 even though i opened the 2014 management studio.
and ideas why ? 

I'm asking in regards to the LAG function issue.